# Making Ubuntu 11.10 bare bones

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-minimal

I was wanting to make Ubuntu bare bones, i.e. with no glitter and zitter so that it becomes highly responsive and quick to boot up. I heard gnome is one thing which can make the os less responsive, but are there less "system intensive" version which I can revert back to.
Rather than trying another faster OS I want to try and make Ubuntu faster, which would work out great.

Digvijay

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! How "bare bones" do you mean? Do you still want Unity? Do you still want a graphical interface at all?

Comment: Ubuntu was being laggy, in opening software (I had already installed preload), when I was opening new tabs in my browser, or the unity side dock, everything was coming in bits and all of a sudden.
So now I think I would like to have minimal gui, no unity, i have to have gui(but minimal) and keyboard shortcuts and maybe a menu like in 10.10. How to go about it? EDIT: There must be other stuff I haven't thought of obviously, so I am open to anything.